# Why do facebook and google pages have strange ids and classes?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, google-plus

Many a times I have inspected element on facebook and google pages but their page always have strange values as ids and classes in their html elements. Have a look at

**Attributes of an element on facebook page**

[image]

**Attributes of element on google plus page**

[image]

Q1. Is this result of some kind of obfuscation algorithm ?

It would be a nightmare to code with such attributes if devs actually use them which I don't think so.

Q2. Why are they doing it ?

Comment: It's generated from something else. Developers never deal with them directly.

Comment: Strange IDs and Classes prevents Websites from Hackers,Hackers see Strange classes,they get scared and dont even think of Hacking such site.StackOverfluw   is also same in that way.

Comment: Its just a way to prevent site from being hacked by the hackers...

Comment: Oh right..So basically providing random ids and classes prevent your page from running a particular script and manipulating some content..If somehow a script gets access to the page..This point make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's likely that they generate new classes and ids with each time the build is run to avoid having caching issues... this would be something thats done via the build and not defined by the developers

Comment: +1 For highlighting a nice concept..Any idea how do they do it ? Any framework name ?

Comment: I am sure both google and facebook have quite custom and elaborate build mechanisms in place that are not publicly available, however, google closure tools has ability to do something like this in its advanced compiler, though you have to be using their templating markup and stylesheet precompiler to do so...  there are some grunt plugins that will do parts of this but i dont think there is one that does it all... maybe a good side project =)

Comment: Caching of what actually?

Comment: updated css, js, images, etc... updated hashes ensure that your latest and greatest is always pulled down, a fairly common practice is generating MD5 hashes of all of your resources at build time and appending to the filenames... by doing this the unmodified files retain the same hashes but any with changes will get a fresh hash

Answer (score 1):

Other answers partially answer this. Its not to deal with caching.
Its not to avoid hackers, just makes their work a little more fun.
Its mainly to reduce page size and improve bandwidth use. Its called js minifying. Its automated before publishing the code. It can be a pain to debug but there are tools to unminify which help.
Also using 'caja' or closure compiler also causes this and provides protection from the js itself.